# TreeView Menu with hyperlinks in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

I've made a search in Google but not found any sample with a TreeView menu with hyperlinks like on MSDN site.

by eg. I have

```
<controls:TreeView>
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Home">
        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Services"/>
        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="About"/>
```

How can I associate menu items with links on the site? Should I manage "Selected" event to reset the ContentFrame Source to the linked URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try changing the template of the Header? here's a sample:

```
<Controls:TreeView>
    <Controls:TreeViewItem>
        <Controls:TreeViewItem.Header>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="About" NavigateUri="/About"/>
        </Controls:TreeViewItem.Header>
    </Controls:TreeViewItem>
</Controls:TreeView>
```

Hope this helps ;)